# How to back up a complete SQLite database to the cloud

Tags: android, database, cloud, backup, database-backups

I am building my first Android app and I am stuck at a point where I have almost finished the app because I don't know how to backup and restore the database to and from the cloud.

The point is, the app has a SQLite database with about ten tables. I was thinking of how to backup the whole database with all ten tables and to restore it just as it is when the user reinstalls the app.

I also wanted to give the user the opportunity to select options as to how frequent backups should be done, like say every 24 hours, one week or one month. I also wanted it in a way that, if the user reinstalls the app, it should restore the database before the user can do anything with the app, else if the backup is not restored the user shouldn't be able to access the app.

I have searched so many sites and have not found a solution.

Comment: You are asking two questions. One: how do I copy the sqlite database to a file (like on /sdcard) and Two: how do I copy that file to a server. Both questions have been answered on Stackoverflow before. Just google for them.

Comment: Ok. I will do that. Thanks sir.

Comment: Errr... "Ma'am" will do.